# How to request elevation data from ERDAS Apollo?

Tags: elevation, wcs, udig, erdas-apollo

I'm developing a custom application(Desktop based using uDig SDK) where user have a provision to select the line feature on map to view its elevation chart.

So far I can do this using Google elevation API (as it returns elevation values in JSON format using which I can render a chart with the help of Google chart API).

Now I want to do the same task by requesting the elevation data from ERDAS Apollo (i think it supports WCS) as client has hosted elevation data i.e. DEM on his ERDAS Apollo server, but I don't find any helpful documentation on "How to request elevation data from ERDAS Apollo".

Answer (score 1):

ERDAS Apollo does support WCS, so to request elevation data from a DEM, you just need to make a GetCoverage request with some subsettting to delineate the location of your choosing, that is you do a GetCoverage request to get at the raw data value in the DEM.